# How do I configure a secondary gateway in RHEL5?

Tags: linux, networking, redhat, gateway

Greetings, we have been experiencing a random timeout issue with VPN users connecting to one of our servers which is causing a problem. My network administrator has instructed me to configure a secondary gateway to include the VPN connection.

My current connection resides as follows, 10.1.9.1 is the internal gateway to the internet, I'd like to add 10.1.1.20 as the VPN gateway.

```
# Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5708S Gigabit Ethernet
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
BROADCAST=10.1.255.255
IPADDR=10.1.1.22
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
NETMASK=255.255.0.0
NETWORK=10.1.0.0
ONBOOT=yes
GATEWAY=10.1.9.1
TYPE=Ethernet
USERCTL=no
IPV6INIT=no
PEERDNS=yes
```

Answer (score 2):

create a file in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` called `route-eth1` (or whatever is the name of your interface) with the route rule, for example:

`10.0.0.0/8 via 10.1.1.20`

Comment: Would this set a secondary route or would this become a single route? i.e, will I need to add one line in that format for each mask to route on? Sorry for the delay in response.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't knew the rule syntax pulegium suggests, which if suppored, is definetively more elegant that what I use.

But, just in case, on my systems I do the same but with the following syntax. In /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0 put:

```
ADDRESS0=10.0.0.0
NETMASK0=255.0.0.0
GATEWAY0=10.1.1.20
```

And then do a network restart.